# Can I connect from Cloud Run to a Postgres instance hosted in Compute Engine? (not Cloud SQL)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I wish to connect Cloud Run to a Postgres database running in port 5432 in Compute Engine (not Cloud SQL). I assume from the documentation that this cannot be done. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All depend how do you want to reach your database.

- If you want (can) reach them from internet, simply create a connection between the compute engine public IP in your Cloud Run container. Don't forget to open the port 5432 for 0.0.0.0/0 IP in firewall rules. You understand that it's not the most secure...
- If you want to reach privately your compute engine, I mean by using the private IP of the compute engine and passing by your VPC, you can't today with Cloud Run. [Serverless VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) should come in 2020, but until this release, you can't.

*Note: In both case, don't forget to set up your connexion pool equal to the concurrency param to save/preserve your database connexion. On the same concern, you can set up a max instance limit to not use too many connexion to your database.*

Comment: Hi, as this is pretty much a showstopper for us to implementing cloud run today, is there a timeline/alpha program or something from Google as to when this will be available?

Comment: I don't have any date to communicate (and I can't!!). Anyway, Cloud Next is in April, the 6th, and I hope a lot of great announcement around this date!

Comment: ok, thanks.  Hopefully something will come out at that time then. :)